# Resetting Primary Key (pk) Sequence in Django Factory Boy for Each Test

Tags: python, django, testcase, factory-boy

I'm trying to figure out how to reset the factory model's primary key (pk) sequence in Django when using FactoryBoy for testing. Consider the following sample model and tests:

```py
class Profile(DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
```

Now I want to test it:

```py
class FirstTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(UserScoresTest, cls).setUpClass()
        Profile.create()
        Profile.create()

class SecondTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(UserScoresTest, cls).setUpClass()
        Profile.create()
        Profile.create()
```

After running these tests, the Profiles' primary keys (pk) in SecondTest have values 3 and 4, respectively. I want to reset the pk sequence before each test. What should I do?

Comment: Can I ask *why* you'd want the pk to reset? It makes some sense to test for matching keys where you need them, etc. - but testing for a specific value of a pk seems like a bad idea, more so because the generation of the pk is hidden implementation, and the value should have no meaning within your code (unless you generate it yourself)?

Comment: @Grismar The reason I want to reset the primary key (pk) sequence is that I have distinct test scenarios in FirstTest and SecondTest within the same file. In FirstTest, I'm solely focusing on testing the ProfileFactory. However, in SecondTest, I extend the testing scope to include scenarios involving the ProfileFactory with additional relations like PointFactory().

Comment: I suppose I get that, but writing your tests to rely on constant pks includes an assumption about the underlying database that you shouldn't rely on. Having said that, the solution seems to be to just run some SQL to get the underlying RDBMS to reset the table? (or even just to recreate it?)